# How to implement a slider in elm

Tags: elm

I want to link a slider and a input text area such that when I change one the other is automatically updated. I found elm-reactor's implementation, which uses native JavaScript and works with a callback. The callback is called whenever the slider is moved but I can't get it to move when the value is changed from the text area...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's not that hard in fact. This code shows how to set the value of the two input types. See [ellie](https://ellie-app.com/9hNhqLk4vgwa1) for example

**Update for 0.19**

```
type alias Model =
    Int


type Msg
    = Update String


update : Msg -> Model -> Model
update (Update v) model =
    String.toInt v |> Maybe.withDefault 0


view model =
    div []
        [ input
            [ type_ "range"
            , Attrs.min "0"
            , Attrs.max "20"
            , value <| String.fromInt model
            , onInput Update
            ]
            []
        , text <| String.fromInt model
        ]
```

**Update for 0.18**

```
import Html exposing (Attribute, div, text, input)
import Html.Attributes as H exposing (..)
import Html.Events exposing (on, onInput)
import Json.Decode exposing (string, map)
import String

type alias Model = Int

type Msg
    = Update String

update : Msg -> Model -> Model
update (Update v) model =
    String.toInt v |> Result.withDefault 0

view model =
  div []
    [ input
      [ type_ "range"
      , H.min "0"
      , H.max "20"
      , value <| toString model
      , onInput Update
      ] []
    , text <| toString model
    ]

main =
  Html.beginnerProgram
    { model = 0
    , view = view
    , update = update
    }
```

**Update for 0.17**

```
import Html exposing (Attribute, div, text, input)
import Html.App as Html
import Html.Attributes as H exposing (..)
import Html.Events exposing (on, onInput)
import Json.Decode exposing (string, map)
import String

type alias Model = Int

type Msg
    = Update String

update : Msg -> Model -> Model
update (Update v) model =
    String.toInt v |> Result.withDefault 0

view model =
  div []
    [ input
      [ type' "range"
      , H.min "0"
      , H.max "20"
      , value <| toString model
      , onInput Update
      ] []
    , text <| toString model
    ]

main =
  Html.beginnerProgram
    { model = 0
    , view = view
    , update = update
    }
```

** Original O.16 version **

```
import Html exposing (div, text, input)
import Html.Attributes as H exposing (..)
import Html.Events as E 

mbox = 
  Signal.mailbox "0"

view v =
  let 
    evth = E.on "change" E.targetValue (Signal.message mbox.address)
  in
  div [] 
    [ input 
      [ type' "range"
      , H.min "0"
      , H.max "20"
      , value v
      , evth
      ] []
    , input
      [ type' "text", value v, evth ] []
    ]


main =
  Signal.map view mbox.signal
```

Comment: Now the 1 million dollar question: why did they resort to native to implement this in elm-reactor and where is it used?

Comment: `Graphics.Input` doesn't support sliders, and maybe it should, but `elm-html` has become the *de facto* view standard - as this example shows. I think the slider is used to scrub time.

Comment: Updated my answer - have been trying to get my head around mailboxes of late and this was a chance to test that I had everything straight

Comment: Note for anyone using Elm 0.19+: `toString` is no longer exposed from the Basics module, use `String.fromInt` instead.

Answer (score 4):

**Updated to Elm 0.19** from banncee's update to 0.18 from Simon H's original answer

```
import Browser
import Html exposing (Attribute, div, text, input)
import Html.Attributes as H exposing (..)
import Html.Events exposing (on, onInput)

type alias Model = Int

type Msg
    = Update String

init : Model
init = 0

update : Msg -> Model -> Model
update (Update v) model =
    case String.toInt v of
        Just i -> i
        Nothing -> model

view model =
  div []
    [ input
      [ type_ "range"
      , H.min "0"
      , H.max "20"
      , value  <| String.fromInt model
      , onInput Update
      ] []
    , text <|String.fromInt model
    ]

main =
    Browser.sandbox
        { init = init
        , view = view
        , update = update
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

The basic idea is to have one canonical representation of the number in your model. Whenever it changes (that would be an action), you don't care where the change came from, you just update the model. And then you render both the text area and the slider based on the value of the number in the model. (We're talking a single text field with just the number, not a free form paragraph box, right?)

Hope that helps!

Comment: Yes, it does, thanks. But unfortunately, I only supply a callback to the slider (see https://github.com/elm-lang/elm-reactor/blob/master/frontend/Slider.elm)

Answer (score 1):

From Simon H's original answer, **Update for Elm 0.18:**

```
import Html exposing (Attribute, div, text, input, beginnerProgram)
import Html.Attributes as H exposing (..)
import Html.Events exposing (on, onInput)

type alias Model = Int

type Msg
    = Update String

update : Msg -> Model -> Model
update (Update v) model =
    String.toInt (Debug.log "" v) |> Result.withDefault 0

view model =
  div []
    [ input
      [ type_ "range"
      , H.min "0"
      , H.max "20"
      , value <| toString model
      , onInput Update
      ] []
    , text <| toString model
    ]

main =
  Html.beginnerProgram
    { model = 0
    , view = view
    , update = update
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime, there are libraries to create sliders:

- [stephenreddek/elm-range-slider](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/stephenreddek/elm-range-slider/latest/)
- [carwow/elm-slider](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/carwow/elm-slider/latest/)